# How to program Bios to automatically power up the computer at a specific date and time

Tags: delphi, bios

I want to set the BIOS to power up the computer at a specific date and time. I can do it directly in BIOS but I want to do it in a program (made with Delphi).

I am aware that I can do this with scheduled tasks but I specifically wish to avoid using them.

I saw other programs that are able to do that so it's doable.

Does anyone know how to implement this...?

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Comment: You cannot tell the computer to turn on, but you can tell it to wake up. Is that sufficient?

Comment: As you see it - what is the difference between them...?

Comment: John, posting an example of *those other programs* would help.

Comment: why consider bios when you can do it with a scheduled task?

Comment: @Lieven for example the Record scheduler from my TVTunner application. I set a date/time, it turns off the computer completely, the computer starts at that time/date and begin recording the TV program. If you want I'll post it on mediafire. But is working only with that TVTunner program. @David Because if I'm missing from home a few days and I want to program the computer to do something, I don't see the point keeping it on for days...

Comment: @john you can program tasks. I don't think you understood my point at all.

Comment: here are some links: http://www.bioscentral.com/misc/cmosmap.htm and http://sourceforge.net/projects/nvram-wakeup/ I hope this have some value. @David how would you explain that to a customer who asks you for a special application that can set the wake up time of the PC?! like: keep DELETE button pressed while the system is starting? and then you lost him... because from there on you're talking lost ancient languages :-P anyhu let me know if you find anything John, I'm interested in something like that as well, cheers!!

Comment: @dorin I don't see what's directed at me in your comment. Sorry.

Comment: I just don't see why you wouldn't use the mechanism that's built into Windows to do this.

Comment: maybe for learning purpose? it doesn't matter after all, it's a question, if we can't help, then we're wasting time.............................................................

Comment: @Dorin Thank you. @David I don't like scheduled tasks. It's one of the first things that I deactivate in Windows + I would like to make my custom made program who will do things exactly the way I want.

Comment: @John You realise that you can drive the task scheduler programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383606%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: same here, I'm a control freak myself :-P

Comment: @David you do realise that he can also create a cross platform solution INDEPENDENT of the OS, right?

Comment: @Dorin Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: @Dorin: Yup, you can always do like Linus did: write your OS from scratch. you can even do that without ASM using HEX or binary. It might turn out into a mind blowing thing that a lot of people like. Give it a few years though...

Comment: @Jeron nahhh you need to be a "I can" guy to do that, I can't smell any "I can" just "do whatever", regarding Linux, I'm not sure to what you're refering, the kernel or distro's?

Comment: @David: you should turn that link into an answer. It will gain upvotes for sure.

Comment: @Dorin Linus is a genius and he wrote on OS kernel all by himself that, I believe, is included on more new devices than any other. That's "can do" in my book.

Answer (score 9):

Although the OP has explicitly stated in comments that he does not wish to use scheduled tasks, some people reading this may be interested to know that it is possible with scheduled tasks.

This can be done from the task scheduler's GUI interface, from the command line or even in code using the [Task Scheduler Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383606%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, it's a solution so I will vote it. But I will still try to make it without scheduled tasks.

Comment: You cannot use scheduled tasks to power-up a PC, when the PC is off the task scheduler is not running. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Sertac My computer starts up at 6am every week day to build my app and run regression tests. It does this with a scheduled task.

Comment: yes, windows knows how to write into bios settings(which varies from manufacturer to manufacturer), basically it gives you a simple UI to do what you can do from bios.

Comment: +1. And to the OP: If Windows has an option to set up the "wake on now" feature of your BIOS, use it, because Windows will likely overwrite your changes anyway.

Comment: @Cosmin windows will most like NOT overwrite unless you set up an event that needs to overwrite.

Comment: Unaccepting 5 years later is odd. What has changed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is specific to the board manufacturer. Allowing arbitrary applications to modify bios settings is a security risk and is generally prevented by both the BIOS and OS. Both Dell and HP provide software which is tied to their hardware that can modify *some* system settings but I don't think this is available to just any application. My HP laptop came with a utility to change a few system settings without needing to go to the CMOS setup screen but most management software I've seen targets enterprise servers and workstations.

http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/by-technology-systems-management.aspx
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html

You can also check out the [Distributed Management Taskforce](http://dmtf.org/standards). It is a standards body that maintains specifications for querying BIOS settings. I haven't looked deep enough to see if there is a standard for changing settings as well.